# Java. Class parameters not passing through constructors

Tags: java, object

This is the main program, when I create and manage the object.

```
public class ShoppingCartManager {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
           //when declaring the object it's not changing the values.
       ShoppingCart cart1 = new ShoppingCart("John Doe", "February 1, 2016");
       System.out.println(cart1.getCustomerName());
       
    }

}//end of class
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

This is the class, the constructer should write to the classe's private variables but they don't update.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ShoppingCart {

    private String customerName = "none";
    private String currentDate = "January 1, 2016";
    //ArrayList<ItemToPurchase> cartItems = new ArrayList<ItemToPurchase>();
    
    //constructor methods
        //this is constructer that it calls
    ShoppingCart(String Name, String Date) {
        //Parameterized constructor which takes the customer name and date as parameters
        String customerName = Name;
        String currentDate = Date;
    }
    ShoppingCart() {
        //String customerName - Initialized in default constructor to "none"
        //String currentDate - Initialized in default constructor to "January 1, 2016"
        String customerName = "none";
        String currentDate = "January 1, 2016";
    }

ShoppingCart(String Name) {
String customerName = Name;
}

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    //Getter methods
    
    //getCustomerName
    public String getCustomerName(){
        return customerName;
    }
    //getDate
    public String getDate() {
        return currentDate;
    }
    
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}//end of class
```

I tried remaking the constructors and creating new objects. But the object customerName variable would always stay at the default "none".

Comment: `String customerName = Name;` -> `customerName = Name;` (and same for all fields you're trying to set).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class ShoppingCart {

private String customerName = "none";
private String currentDate = "January 1, 2016";
//ArrayList<ItemToPurchase> cartItems = new ArrayList<ItemToPurchase>();

// Parameterized constructor
ShoppingCart(String name, String date) {
    this.customerName = name; // Assign the parameter to the class field
    this.currentDate = date; // Assign the parameter to the class field
}

// Default constructor
ShoppingCart() {
    // The class fields are already initialized with default values, so you could leave this empty or remove it if you don't need to do anything else.
}

ShoppingCart(String name) {
    this.customerName = name; // Assign the parameter to the class field
    // currentDate will retain its default value unless explicitly set
}

// Getter methods

public String getCustomerName() {
    return customerName;
}

public String getDate() {
    return currentDate;
}
```

The issue you're encountering in your ShoppingCart class arises from how you're handling assignments within your constructor. When you're assigning values to customerName and currentDate inside the constructor, you're actually creating and assigning values to local variables rather than updating the class fields. This is why your customerName always remains at its default value of "none". To fix this issue, you should remove the data type declaration inside the constructors when setting the values. This way, you ensure that you're assigning the provided values to the class's fields rather than to new, local variables. This should work.